# Showing $\int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{\ln(z)}{z^4+1}dz = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I need help showing:
$$\int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{\ln(z)}{z^4+1}dz = 0$$

where $\Gamma_R$ is the semi-circle with radius R centered at the origin.

I wanted to use the estimation lemma to prove that this integral goes to zero, but I'm having trouble. I'm aware the lemma is:

$$\left|\int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{\ln(z)}{z^4+1}dz\right| \le M*l(\Gamma_R)$$
I know $l(\Gamma_R)$ is $\pi R$ but I'm not sure how to go about finding M. I've looked at other posts using the triangle inequality, but I'm not sure how to use it here. Any help that is in pretty laymen's-terms would be much appreciative!

Comment: The integral tends to zero when the radius tends to infinity, but it does not equal zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I choose $R>1$ . Notice that for $R_1>1$ the paths $\Gamma_{R}$ is homotopic to $\Gamma_{R_1}$. So that 
$$\int_{\Gamma_{R}} \frac{\ln(z)}{z^4+1}dz =\int_{\Gamma_{R_1}} \frac{\ln(z)}{z^4+1}dz $$ 
Now $$|\int_{\Gamma_{R_1}} \frac{\ln(z)}{z^4+1}dz|≤length(\Gamma_{R_1})\  sup_{z\in \Gamma_{R_1}} |f(z)| $$
Next $$sup_{z\in \Gamma_{R_1}} |f(z)|=sup_{z\in \Gamma_{R_1}}\frac{|ln|z|+\iota arg(z)|}{|z^4+1|} ≤    sup_{z\in \Gamma_{R_1}}\frac{|ln|z||+c}{|z^4|-1}=\frac{ln(R_1)+c}{R_1^4-1}  $$
Therefore  $$    |\int_{\Gamma_{R}} \frac{\ln(z)}{z^4+1}dz| =    |\int_{\Gamma_{R_1}} \frac{\ln(z)}{z^4+1}dz|≤length(\Gamma_{R_1})\  sup_{z\in \Gamma_{R_1}} |f(z)| ≤\pi R_1  \frac{ln(R_1)+c}{R_1^4-1}\rightarrow 0\ as \ R_1\rightarrow \infty$$

Here $$ln:\Bbb C-\{r(cos(\alpha)+\iota sin(\alpha)): r≥0, \alpha=-\pi/2\}\rightarrow \Bbb C,\ ln(z)=ln(|z|)+\iota arg(z)$$ and $$arg:\Bbb C-\{r(cos(\alpha)+\iota sin(\alpha)): r≥0, \alpha=-\pi/2\}\rightarrow (-\pi/2,2\pi-\pi/2)$$  are continuous functions. And $c$ is some fixed constant such that $c≥|arg(z)|$ on $\Gamma_{R_1}$ and for each $R_1>1$. Hence
$$\int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{\ln(z)}{z^4+1}dz = 0$$

Comment: It's not true that the integrals over $\Gamma_R$ and  $\Gamma_{R_1}$ are equal. The contours are semicircles, they don't have the same endpoints.

Comment: You are right. Actually, $\int_{\Gamma_{R}} \frac{\ln(z)}{z^4+1}dz =\int_{\Gamma_{R_1}} \frac{\ln(z)}{z^4+1}dz+\int_{-R_1}^{-R}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^4+1}dx+\int_R^{R_1}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^4+1}dx$, as $\Gamma_{R}$ is path homotopic to $L[-R_1,-R]+\Gamma_{R_1}+L[R,R_1]$ relataive to $\{±R\}$. And the last two integrals tends to zero as $R_1\to\infty$ by same way.

Comment: The integrals over $[-R_1, R]$ and $[R, R_1]$ tend to zero when $(R, R_1) \to (\infty, \infty)$, not for a fixed $R$. You can't prove that the integral over $\Gamma_R$ is zero, that statement is false.